# "Questions typiques vs "questions type"

Tags: usage, synonymes

What is the difference between:

> Est-il possible de nous envoyer un ou plusieurs exercices type pour qu'on puisse s'entraîner ?

et

> Est-il possible de nous envoyer un ou plusieurs exercices typiques pour qu'on puisse s'entraîner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the first form is more likely to be used, with *question ou exercice type* meaning questions or exercices that represent what to expect, models, while *questions / exercices typiques* alone is slightly odd, as *typique* is often close to *exotic*.

On the other hand, you might say *Est-il possible de nous envoyer des exemples d'exercices typiques de ce sur quoi on peut tomber lors de l'examen de troisième année*.